# Stripping blank XML tags from PHP generated XML files?

Tags: php, xml

I have generated an XML file from my database using the PHP DOM functions. I then save this to a file using dom->save("feed.xml").

The problem I'm facing is that some of the rows in my database have empty feilds, resulting in this type of output -

```
<summary/>
```

as the summary field is empty.

Is it possible to remove these tags without affecting other nodes? The reason I want to remove them as the XML will eventually be fed to an app and I don't want it to take in blank fields as this is somewhat inconsistent.

Does anyone know of a way to acheive what I desire?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you not do a check to see if the value of the field is 'empty' before creating the node?

Comment: So in theory before looping through my query results I could check to see which were empty?

Comment: @JesseOrange While looping your query check if value is empty, if not, set node, else don't add empty node.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xpath()` to select all empty nodes and delete them:

**Example XML:**

```
<root>
    <test/>
    <test></test>
    <test>
        <name>Michi</name>
        <name/>
    </test>    
</root>
```

**PHP:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// select any node at any position in the tree that has no children and no text
// store them in array $results
$results = $xml->xpath("//*[not(node())]");

// iterate and delete
foreach ($results as $r) unset($r[0]);

// display new XML
echo $xml->asXML();
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <test>
        <name>Michi</name>    
    </test>    
</root>
```

see it working: https://eval.in/236071